# Evaluate the limit or show that is does not exist

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1-\cos(3x)}{2x^2}$$

So far I have noted

$$\frac{1-\cos(3x)}{2x^2} = \frac{1-\cos(3x)}{2x^2} \cdot \frac{1+\cos(3x)}{1+\cos(3x)}$$

and then used the identity $$\sin^2x = 1-\cos^2x$$ to reduce this to

$$\frac{\sin^2(9x)}{2x^2+\cos(9x)}.$$
Any tips on how to proceed?

Comment: Is the question this $\frac{1-\cos(3x)}{2x}$ or this $1-\frac{\cos(3x)}{2x}$

Comment: The first one (1-cos3x)/(2x)

Comment: The substitution $u = 3x\;$ (and $2x = \frac{2}{3}u)$ will turn it into (a multiple of) a limit that you may recognize.

Comment: Note that your application of $\sin^2 x = 1 - \cos^2 x$ (and algebra in general) is incorrect on the last line. Indeed, this actually simplifies to $\frac{1-\cos^2(3x)}{2x(1+\cos(3x))}$.

Comment: @LittleJon Please note that you have done some serious mistake in the last step where you have changed the $3x$ to $9x$ and also in the denominator, there should be $x$ instead of $x^2$.

Comment: so sorry I forgot to put 2x^2 on the denominator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Given:** $L=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1-\cos(3x)}{2x^2}$

$\implies L=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1-\cos(3x)}{(3x)^2} \times \frac{(3x)^2}{2x^2}$

$\implies L=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{9x^2}{2x^2}$   **[Using $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^2}=\frac{1}{2}$]**

$\implies \boxed{L= \frac{9}{4}}$

**EDIT: I have changed my solution based on the changes in your question.**

Answer (score 0):

You had the right idea, but your algebra is suspect. For example, $\cos 3x \cdot \cos 3x \ne \cos^2 9x$
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1-\cos 3x}{2x} = \frac{3}{2}\cdot\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1-\cos 3x}{3x}$$
$$= \frac{3}{2}\cdot\lim_{3x\to 0} \frac{1-\cos 3x}{3x}$$
$$= \frac{3}{2}\cdot\lim_{\theta\to 0} \frac{1-\cos \theta}{\theta}$$
where $\theta = 3x$

$$= \frac{3}{2}\cdot\lim_{\theta\to 0} \frac{1-\cos \theta}{\theta}\cdot \frac{1+\cos \theta}{1+\cos \theta}$$
$$= \frac{3}{2}\cdot\lim_{\theta\to 0} \frac{1-\cos^2 \theta}{\theta}\cdot \frac{1}{1+\cos \theta}$$
$$= \frac{3}{2}\cdot\lim_{\theta\to 0} \frac{\sin^2 \theta}{\theta}\cdot \frac{1}{1+\cos \theta}$$
$$= \frac{3}{2}\cdot\lim_{\theta\to 0} \frac{\sin \theta}{\theta}\cdot \frac{\sin \theta}{1+\cos \theta}$$
$$= \frac{3}{2}\cdot\lim_{\theta\to 0} \frac{\sin \theta}{\theta}\cdot \lim_{\theta\to 0}\frac{\sin \theta}{1+\cos \theta}$$
$$= \frac{3}{2}\cdot\frac{0}{1+1}\cdot\lim_{\theta\to 0} \frac{\sin \theta}{\theta}$$
$$= 0\cdot\lim_{\theta\to 0} \frac{\sin \theta}{\theta}$$
$$= 0$$

Now all that is required is to prove that $\displaystyle\lim_{\theta\to 0} \frac{\sin \theta}{\theta} = 1$ (or at the very least, that it exists).

on $(0, \pi/2)$
$$0 \lt \sin \theta \lt \theta$$
$$0/\theta \lt \sin \theta / \theta \lt \theta/\theta$$
$$0 \lt \frac{\sin \theta}{\theta} \lt 1$$

thus $ 0 \le \displaystyle\lim_{\theta\to 0}\frac{\sin \theta}{\theta} \le 1$
and
$$0\cdot 0 \le 0\cdot \displaystyle\lim_{\theta\to 0}\frac{\sin \theta}{\theta} \le 0\cdot1$$
$$0 \le 0\cdot \displaystyle\lim_{\theta\to 0}\frac{\sin \theta}{\theta} \le 0$$

$$\therefore 0\cdot \displaystyle\lim_{\theta\to 0}\frac{\sin \theta}{\theta} = 0$$

Answer (score -1):

You would have  have it here as follows if your algebra were correct.
$$\frac{\sin^2(9x)}{2x^2+\cos(9x)}.$$
As $x\to 0$, $\sin^2(9x) \to 0$ and $2x^2 + \cos(9x)\to 1.$
The limit of the ratio is zero.

However, the algebra leading up to your expression is flawed. I made the mistake
of not checking your preceding calculations.

$$\frac{1-\cos(3x)}{2x^2} = \frac{1-\cos(3x)}{2x^2} \cdot \frac{1+\cos(3x)}{1+\cos(3x)} ={\sin^2(3x)\over 2x^2(1 + \cos(3x))} \sim {\sin^2(3x)\over 4x^2}\to {9\over 4} $$
as $x\to 0.$

Comment: The expression you have there is algebraically and trigonometrically wrong.